# sync rack request and response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, rack, rackattack

In my rails 4 app I'd like to response with `html` both for `html` and `js` request. At the moment when the request is `html` type the rendering works fine, but when the request is `js` then the html file doesn't get rendered on the screen (although in the command line it says it's rendered).

There are different scenarios for limiting requests so the throttle code can be triggered by `html POST` and `js POST` request as well.

```
Rack::Attack.throttle(key, limit: from_config(key, :limit), period: from_config(key, :period)) do |req|
  if req.path.ends_with?(from_config(key, :path).to_s) && from_config(key, :method) == req.env['REQUEST_METHOD']
    ### This is the snippet I try to change the req type with but not working
    if req.media_type == 'application/javascript'
      req.media_type = 'text/html'
    end
    ##### till here
    req.ip
  end
end
```

Here is what I'm trying to render. As you see this is `html` response.

```
Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
  [429, {}, [ActionView::Base.new.render(file: 'public/429.html', content_type: 'text/html')]]
end
```

What should I do?

UPDATE

This is my newest version, but can't figure out how to check the request content_type:

```
Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
  retry_after = (env['rack.attack.match_data'] || {})[10]
  if env['rack.attack.content_type'] == 'text/html'
    [429, {'Retry-After' => retry_after.to_s}, [ActionView::Base.new.render(file: 'public/429.html', content_type: 'text/html')]]
  elsif env['rack.attack.content_type'] == 'application/javascript'
    [429, {'Retry-After' => retry_after.to_s}, window.location.href = '/429.html']
  end
end
```

docs:  https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? It would make more sense to create a custom mime type or use headers to check if it is a XHR request rather than mess up one of the existing mime types.

Comment: Most browsers wont render the response as HTML either if the request has something other than `accept: text/html`.

Comment: max, can you show me how to do that? I don't know why this would mess anything up, since this happens only if sby exceeds the limit for some action.

Comment: I kind of missed the part about throttling, do you really need / want to return a html response? If a client has been throttled you should return `429` and either a blank response or javascript containing a comment as to not break clients that might actually be expecting a JS response and will try to parse the response as javascript.

Comment: As a developer I would find that a lot more helpful than my script blowing up  due to a pretty error page.

Comment: max, the problem is that the request that will be throttled can be both js and html. For example logging in is an html request, but commenting on a post is js. If I set the js response as you say then it won't response to the html request. So this question is not about the error page (js response version is ok with me), but rather about how to response properly to different requests.

Comment: Any combination is okay: `1. html req => html resp, js req => html resp` (I'm trying this at the moment.), `2. html req => js resp, js req => js resp`, `3. html req => html resp, js req => js resp` (this one needs some conditional). The problem is I don't know how to code any of these.

Comment: max, my friend told me `window.location.href = '/429.html'` would work for js response, but to have that I have to figure out how to check the `request type` first. I went thru the docs but my ruby skills are not there yet. So at the moment `env['rack.attack.content_type']` is the piece of code that not working. Could you tell me how I can check the request type?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @max. In principle, you should not respond with HTML to a request specifically for JS.

But to answer this part of the question:

> how to check the request content_type:

Try checking this instead:

```
req.env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
```

**Explanation**

1. `req` [is an object that subclasses](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/lib/rack/attack/request.rb) `Rack::Request`.
2. [Rack prepends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318491) `HTTP_` to the client's HTTP request headers and adds them to the `env` hash.
3. [HTTP clients can indicate what MIME types they accept](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) in the `Accept` header, as opposed to the `Content-Type` header, where they can indicate what type of data they are sending to you.

Comment: monozok, if you wouldn't do html response then how would you solve this problem? If sby let's say tries to login 10 times (which an html post req) then he will be redirected to a page which says that he made too many requests. But the same should happen when sby comments too much on a post thread. The problem is that it's a js request since normally (within the req number limit) it should just response with a js snippet. So how can I respond with js if within req limit and with html over req limit?

Comment: Ok, rereading your newest version, I see you are responding with JS that tells the browser to redirect. So I don't have a problem with that. My bad!

Comment: accept works fine but it seems like req.env['HTTP_CONTENT-TYPE'] is not supported? even though its valid header

Comment: Maybe it’s HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE with all underscores?